# PIL - are there a any PIL solutions that will allow you to take a screenshot of a specified web page?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is there a way to take a screenshot using PIL of an specified HTML/Javascript page that resides on my server?

I want to write a script that will change some parameters on that HTML page and then have PIL take screenshots of it.

Any ideas? Examples would be truly appreciated.

Comment: See http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm.  Works only on Windows.  So you are going to run a browser on your server?

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski I was thinking more like specifying path to an HTML page and then have a screenshot of that page without using a browser. I might be asking too much but I think for want I need is worth asking. I only use Linux so Windows won't work for me. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Why a screenshot?  Why not save a text file?

Comment: What Steven Rumbalski is saying is that to render a page in such a way that you could take a screenshot requires all the same technology that a browser uses to render a web page. So yes, if you're doing this, you're pretty much running a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you absolutely have to use PIL? If not you might be able to get what you want using PyQT which has a built-in Webkit control.

See http://notes.alexdong.com/xhtml-to-pdf-using-pyqt4-webkit-and-headless for an example which converts html+css into a PDF without using a separate browser. The code is pretty short so I've copied it below.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))
#web.show()

printer = QPrinter()
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)
printer.setOutputFileName("file.pdf")

def convertIt():
    web.print_(printer)
    print "Pdf generated"
    QApplication.exit()

QObject.connect(web, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), convertIt)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I don't have to use PIL but I prefer PIL since I use it already on my project.